# codeigniter page not working, error 500

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, apache2

i've a project, its just add new features.
it's using codeigniter 2.2, i'm never using it but i believe i can do it.
i've install the database and setting up configuration properly. but i've got first error.

its say " permission denied" ok i know it. after give a chmod 777 on directory folder, i got error again.
its say **The Localhost page isn't working. HTTP Error 500**.
then i check in the apache error log. the error log is :

[Mon Jan 30 06:13:38.387694 2017] [:error] [pid 3331] [client ::1:55470] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() in /var/www/html/ci226-milba/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php:92\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/ci226-milba/system/database/DB_driver.php(116): CI_DB_mysql_driver->db_pconnect()\n#1 /var/www/html/ci226-milba/system/database/DB.php(149): CI_DB_driver->initialize()\n#2 /var/www/html/ci226-milba/system/core/Loader.php(347): DB(Array, NULL)\n#3 /var/www/html/ci226-milba/system/core/Loader.php(1172): CI_Loader->database()\n#4 /var/www/html/ci226-milba/system/core/Loader.php(153): CI_Loader->_ci_autoloader()\n#5 /var/www/html/ci226-milba/system/core/Controller.php(52): CI_Loader->initialize()\n#6 /var/www/html/ci226-milba/application/controllers/login.php(9): CI_Controller->__construct()\n#7 /var/www/html/ci226-milba/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(309): Login->__construct()\n#8 /var/www/html/ci226-milba/index.php(202): require_once('/var/www/html/c...')\n#9 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/ci226-milba/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php on line 92

this is in my DB Configuration (Application/config/database.php)

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'db_milba';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

whats wrong about that?
my laptop using php7 and mysql 5.6.

Comment: check your error logs and CI had version 3, why are you using 2.2? Btw, mysql_ does not run on PHP 7.

Comment: its solve when i change php version(downgrade to php 5.6). thanks

Answer (score 1):

"mysql" dbdriver is deprecated in PHP 5.5.x.

Instead, use the MySQLi extension and change dbdriver to use mysqli:

`$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';`